# Getting error due to IO a type of parameter

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

I am implementing a feature which is as follows:
User will request for the directory contents via HTTP request. The directory path will be passed inthe request. In response, I will send a JSON containing the list of files for that directory path. IO Error handling is taken care of.
I have implemented most of the part. But I am getting an error. The error is:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘Either IOException [FilePath]’
>             with actual type ‘IO (Either IOException [FilePath])’
> • In the first argument of ‘getJsonRepForFiles’, namely ‘files’
> ```

The code snippet is as follows:

```
getInfoOfDirR::Handler Value
getInfoOfDirR = do
             -- files will have type IO (Either IOException [FilePath])
                     files <- fmap (getListOfFiles.(Data.Text.unpack).fromJust) $ lookupGetParam "dirpath"
                     getJsonRepForFiles files
```

The function which gets list of files:

```
-- This eliminates the hidden files from the results
getListOfFiles::FilePath -> IO (Either IOException [FilePath])
getListOfFiles fpath = try (fmap (filter $ not.isHiddenFile) $  FS.getDirectoryContents fpath)::IO (Either IOException [FilePath])
```

The function which gets JSON representation of the files in the directory:

```
getJsonRepForFiles::Monad m => (Either IOException [FilePath]) -> m Value
getJsonRepForFiles (Left e) = returnJson $ "An error occurred" ++ show e
getJsonRepForFiles (Right files) = returnJson files
```

Note that type of `getInfoOfDirR` is `Handler Value`
I am implementing this in Haskell's Yesod framework.
I am new to Haskell.. I understand somewhat why I am getting the error.
But I am not able to fix it.
Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please note that I have tried using `liftIO` , but it also did not fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that `getListOfFiles` returns a value of type `IO`, and by using it with `fmap` you are creating a `Handler (IO _)`, and the binding in the `do` block only unwraps the `Handler` level.

You could try `join`ing the two levels of the `fmap` result, like:

```
files <- join $ fmap (liftIO. ...
```

Or move the `getListOfFiles` call outside the `fmap` application, like:

```
files <- liftIO . getListOfFiles =<< (fmap ...)
```

Comment: Thanks fo the response. I tried both the approaches. Now I am getting this error:  Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘HandlerT HelloWorld IO’
      Expected type: HandlerT
                       HelloWorld IO (Either IOException [FilePath])
        Actual type: IO (Either IOException [FilePath])

Comment: @ChetanYewale I'm thinking then you would need `files <- liftIO . getListOfFiles =<< (fmap ...)` then. Sorry I assumed `lookupGetParam` returned a type of `IO`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. I wanted to ask you something, I am new to Haskell. I understand the functional programming style. I also understand Functors and Applicatives. I am a somewhat uncomfortable with Monads.  Are there any practice problems that I can do which will gradually help me become better at these concepts? Let me know.. I wish to start with small problems which use Applicatives/Functors/Monads. I also want to understand the typesystem better and avoid the kind of issues that I posted. Is there something that you can suggest?

Comment: @ChetanYewale What had worked best for me was actually implementing a few instances of the `Monad` typeclass to remove some of the "magic". Beside that, doing exactly what it seems you're doing - working through things as they come up (at least, nothing ever seems to stick for me unless I've actually *used* it to solve a problem).

Comment: @ChetanYewale Are you comfortable using the monadic properties of say, `Maybe` and `Either` - the concept of once you get to a certain state, you "can't" go any further? It comes down to the `>>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Given an `m a`, you need to be able to get an `a` to pass to the second parameter to get an `m b`, but in the `Maybe a` or `Either b a` case, if you have a `Nothing` or a `Left b` you *don't have an `a`* to pass along, so you have no choice but to stop.

Comment: @ChetanYewale Also, there is a technique for wrapping your transformer stack in a `newtype` and then `deriving` the instances you need/use which frequently lets your avoid the `liftIO`s and can make some helper functions much clearer. I remember seeing a great slideshow/presentation a while ago but can't seem to find it now... the quickest example I could Google up was: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/refactoring-to-a-monad-transformer-stack

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. Yes, I am comfortable with `Maybe` and `Either` . I sure have a long way to go in Haskell :-)  I see the brilliance of Haskell. Although I understand only basic things in Haskell, it certainly has opened a new world and a new way to think.

Comment: @ChetanYewale To be clear - comfortable from the perspective that you can implement the `Functor`/`Applicative`/`Monad` instances yourself? And if so, you could look into `Reader`/`Writer`/`State`. `ST` and `IO` I believe get tricky because the implementation in GHC uses some unboxed primitives. And if individually they are easy you could try stacking them manually.